# Not sure if i'm using react context correcly

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I've created a form in react and after some research i think that if you don't want to use an external library to manage the form, the context could be the best choice, expecially in my case where i've many nested component that compose it.
But, i'm not sure that putting a function inside my state is a good thing.
But let me give you some code:

**configuration-context.js**

```
import React from 'react'

export const ConfigurationContext = React.createContext();
```

**ConfigurationPanel.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Header, Menu, Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import ConfigurationSection from './ConfigurationSection.jsx'
import {ConfigurationContext} from './configuration-context.js'


class ConfigurationPanel extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { 
            activeItem: '', 
            configuration: {
                       /* the configuration values */
              banana: (data) => /* set the configuration values with the passed data */
            }
        }

    }

    handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name })


    render() {
        return (
            <ConfigurationContext.Provider value={this.state.configuration}>
                <Grid.Row centered style={{marginTop:'10vh'}}>
                    <Grid.Column width={15} >   
                        <div className='configuration-panel'>

                    /* SOME BUGGED CODE */ 

                            <div className='configuration-section-group'>
                                {this.props.data.map((section, i) => <ConfigurationSection key={i} {...section} />)}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Grid.Column>
                </Grid.Row> 
            </ConfigurationContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

**ConfigurationItem.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Input, Dropdown, Radio } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import {ConfigurationContext} from './configuration-context.js'

class ConfigurationItem extends Component {
    static contextType = ConfigurationContext


    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    handleChange = (e, data) => this.context.banana(data)

    itemFromType = (item) =>{
        switch (item.type) {
            case "toggle":
                return  <div className='device-configuration-toggle-container'> 
                            <label>{item.label}</label>
                            <Radio name={item.name} toggle className='device-configuration-toggle'onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div> 

            /* MORE BUGGED CODE BUT NOT INTERESTING*/

        }
    }

    render() {
        return this.itemFromType(this.props.item)
    }
}
```

So, at the end i've a ConfigurationContext that is just a declaration, everything is inside the parent state. 
The thing that i don't like is putting the banana function inside the state (it will have more logic that just logging it)
What do you think about it?
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`banana` is just a regular function and you do not have to put it in the state, just do:

```
class ConfigurationPanel extends Component {
    banana = data => console.log(data)
    ...

    render() {
        return (
            <ConfigurationContext.Provider value={{banana}}>
    ...

}
```

After that you can use `this.context.banana(data)` as normal.

Comment: Yes, sorry My code wasnt clear.... Acrually the function Will set the state with the current edited item of the form, that Will be passed down to the componente, i cant set the value of context with only the function

Comment: Then you can simply change the function content to `banana => data => this.setState({key: data})`

Comment: Well, My code is doing that with some logic inside the banana function, but the point is that i'm not sure that putting a function inside My state to update the context is a good thing

Comment: There is not really a correct way in React as long as the code works. If your question is about convention, then no, I don't see that pattern too often, and I would not recommend you doing so, as it complicates the state and may confuse others reading your code. Perhaps you can read more about useState in React Hook to see how they achieve it properly.